# How can I extend existing vinyl siding downward to cover top of concrete foundation?

Tags: foundation, vinyl-siding, gap

Our new-to-us 1930's home has vinyl siding, but the bottom row of the siding doesn't extend down far enough (see photo). There isn't a starter strip installed that I can find anywhere, either. It looks like the house had some kind of yellow cement board material installed over wood, originally, and then vinyl siding was installed over that about 20 years ago according to the neighbors. The wood in the photos sticks out about 1" away from the house. This isn't attractive, and more importantly, that wood is constantly getting wet from rain running down the siding. So whatever I put there would need to minimally extend down another inch or so, and preferably wrap around the exposed wood to rest against the concrete foundation. Right? The siding is sun-exposed (but in good shape otherwise) so I'm sure that I won't find an exact color match. Perhaps some kind of metal flashing is called for here? We'd like it to look better and to better protect our house. By the way, I just repaired, scraped, and painted the concrete foundation to a similar color as shown in the photo. Thanks for all of your help everyone.

[image: vinyl siding stops above concrete foundation]

Comment: I have a solution but it will require renting a metal brake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the sketch says it all.
I can elaborate if you have questions

[image]

Comment: Whoa, that's an interesting idea that I didn't think of. Should I put in some weep holes into the bottom of the sheet metal (where the nails will be driven through)?

Comment: Yes you can add a few extra drill holes if you choose to you would need to drill the bottom anyway to add the nails to hold it in place